# OpenLayers OverviewMap collapse listener

Tags: openlayers

When using the [ol/control/OverviewMap](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_OverviewMap-OverviewMap.html), how can I add a listener on the expand/collapse button? I circled this button in the image below.  **OverviewMap** has some built in listeners for **change**, **error**, and **propertychange** but the button click doesn't seem to propagate through any of those listeners.

[image: OverviewMap collapse Button circled]

```
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import { OverviewMap } from 'ol/control';

const baseLayer = new TileLayer({
    source: new XYZ({
      url: 'https://gps-c.tile.openstreetmap.org/lines/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    }),
});

const ovMap = new OverviewMap({
  layers: [baseLayer],
  collapseLabel: '\u00BB',
  label: '\u00AB',
  collapsed: true,
});

// myClickListener is undefined, this is just an example of what I would like to do
ovMap.on('myClickListener', () => console.log('overview map was expanded or collapsed'));
```

Here is an example from[Overview Map Example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overviewmap-custom.html)

Comment: It is the map within the control which is changed `ovMap.getOverviewMap().on('change:size', ....`

Comment: @Mike `change:size` doesn't alway trigger on click and always triggers when the browser is resized.

Comment: I got it working by extending the class and adding `this.dispatchEvent('collapseChange');` to `handleClick_` but I really don't like this solution.